# How to create a self-destroying child window to monitor an activity?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117156/create-a-python-tkinter-window-with-no-x-close-button), I wanted to know whether there's a way in Python/Tkinter to create a child window, have it show text progress updates for a 30-60 second process, and then destroy itself when the process completes.  The process in question involves multiple steps such as file copying, database updates, etc.

The linked-to question has a code sample showing the approach I used to create a custom dialog window that collects user input and then closes after an OK/Cancel button is clicked.  I've found that using this same approach doesn't work for the status-update child I want to create.  If I put all the code inside the `showWin` method, I hit a race condition where the window tries to destroy itself before it's displayed (even when I used `update_idletasks`).  But if I try moving the file/DB code to a separate method, there's no event to trigger it and so the processing never happens.

Do I just need to give up on using a child window for this purpose?  Or is there some arrangement that lets the processing happen while avoiding the race condition?

Comment: What you want is almost certainly possible, but your question is too vague.

Comment: What is unclear?  The linked-to article gives the code sample, the text here explains how I was trying to adapt and apply it, and the issues I ran into.  Not trying to be troublesome or snarky, but your comment isn't especially helpful at correcting whatever the problem is with the question.

Comment: There's not enough code in the linked-to question to reproduce your problem, and your statement about a race condition makes no sense. Plus, I have no idea what you mean by the "file/DB code". I see no "file/DB code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but based solely on the title of the question I'm guessing you want some sort of pop-up progress window that destroys itself when progress is complete.

Here's a contrived example that displays a window that self-destructs when progress passes 100%. It's not very bullet-proof, but it shows that it's possible to create a window that self-destructs.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        go_button = tk.Button(text="Go!", command=self.go)
        go_button.pack()

    def go(self):
        self.dialog = ProgressWindow(self)
        self.do_real_work(0)

    def do_real_work(self, count):
        # simulate doing work; update the status window periodically
        self.dialog.set(count)
        self.after(500, lambda count=count+10: self.do_real_work(count))


class ProgressWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="0%")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.wm_geometry("200x200")

    def set(self, value):
        if value > 100:
            self.destroy()
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="%s %%" % value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track.  I fiddled with this a bit and worked out how to get the same result with `do_real_work` as a method of `ProgressWindow`, consisting of a simple linear sequence of processing steps, with the `self.label` text property updates occurring after each step completes.  I'm still puzzling over why my original approach kept throwing an exception (which I took for a race condition).  I note though that this example throws a very similar exception if you click the Go button more than once (see next comment).

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\JDM\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
[...abbreviated...]
  File "C:\JDM\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1253, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: invalid command name ".37857440.38090272.38089992"

Comment: That error means that you are trying to update a widget after it's been destroyed. All it really means is that you need to properly keep track of and cancel any pending activity when you delete the window, or make sure any code that tries to update a widget validates that it exists first. Like I said, this code isn't very bullet proof.