# Disable Exit (or [ X ]) in tkinter Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, exit

I am posting this because I myself have struggled with finding a clear answer on this problem . . .

In search of trying to create a progress bar for my program, I find that it is difficult to do using tkinter. To accomplish creating a progress bar without running into the dreaded "mainloop", [I opted to make a class out of the progress bar using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop). Through lots of trial an error, I found that there is not much that can be customized due to the use of multithreading (tkinter likes being in the main thread). Here are two options I have tried, followed by a third that best fits my needs:

## Option 1: Using a callback function

Given the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading


class ProgressbarApp(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, max_value: int):
        self.max_value = max_value

        self.root = None
        self.pb = None

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()    # (1)
        self.lock.acquire()             # (2)
        self.start()

        # (1) Makes sure progressbar is fully loaded before executing anything
        with self.lock:
            return

    def close(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.__callback)

        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient='horizontal', length=400, mode='determinate')
        self.pb['value'] = 0
        self.pb['maximum'] = self.max_value
        self.pb.pack()

        self.lock.release()             # (2) Will release lock when finished
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self, value: int):
        self.pb['value'] = value

    @staticmethod
    def __callback():
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interval = 100000
    my_pb = ProgressbarApp(interval)

    for i in range(interval):
        my_pb.update(i)

    my_pb.close()

    # Other stuff goes on . . .
```

Where

```
self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.__callback)
```

Prevents the window from being closed. However, if the Exit, or [ X ], button were to be held down, the progress bar would freeze until the user releases the button. (The __callback function is constantly being called, preventing other tasks from being completed).

## Option 2: Using root.overriderdirect(True)

Given the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading


class ProgressbarApp(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, max_value: int):
        self.max_value = max_value

        self.root = None
        self.pb = None

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()    # (1)
        self.lock.acquire()             # (2)
        self.start()

        # (1) Makes sure progressbar is fully loaded before executing anything
        with self.lock:
            return

    def close(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)

        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient='horizontal', length=400, mode='determinate')
        self.pb['value'] = 0
        self.pb['maximum'] = self.max_value
        self.pb.pack()

        self.lock.release()             # (2) Will release lock when finished
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self, value: int):
        self.pb['value'] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interval = 100000
    my_pb = ProgressbarApp(interval)

    for i in range(interval):
        my_pb.update(i)

    my_pb.close()

    # Other stuff goes on . . .
```

Where

```
self.root.overrideredirect(True)
```

Clears all of tkinters window options. However, the progress bar is not only in an odd location, but it also obscures the users window. The progress bar should user friendly.

## Option 3: Using root.attributes('-disabled', True)

Given the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading


class ProgressbarApp(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, max_value: int):
        self.max_value = max_value

        self.root = None
        self.pb = None

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()    # (1)
        self.lock.acquire()             # (2)
        self.start()

        # (1) Makes sure progressbar is fully loaded before executing anything
        with self.lock:
            return

    def close(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-disabled', True)

        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient='horizontal', length=400, mode='determinate')
        self.pb['value'] = 0
        self.pb['maximum'] = self.max_value
        self.pb.pack()

        self.lock.release()             # (2) Will release lock when finished
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self, value: int):
        self.pb['value'] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interval = 100000
    my_pb = ProgressbarApp(interval)

    for i in range(interval):
        my_pb.update(i)

    my_pb.close()

    # Other stuff goes on . . .
```

Where

```
self.root.attributes('-disabled', True)
```

Prevents any user interaction with the window. This has best suited my needs for this program as it prevents the window from closing and still has a nice appearance to it. (My only minor issue with it is that the user can no longer minimize the progress bar or move it around).

If there are any better solutions, I would love to see them. Hopefully, this has helped someone.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a python tkinter window with no X (close) button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117156/create-a-python-tkinter-window-with-no-x-close-button)

Answer (score 12):

You can create a function that just uses `pass` to do nothing.

Take a look at the below:

```
import tkinter as tk


root=tk.Tk()

def close_program():
    root.destroy()

def disable_event():
    pass

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Click me to close", command = close_program)
btn.pack()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

root.mainloop()
```

You could also remove the toolbar all together with `root.overrideredirect(True)` that will prevent the user from using any of the toolbar. leaving `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)` will also prevent the use of `ALT + F4`.

```
import tkinter as tk


root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.overrideredirect(True)

def close_program():
    root.destroy()

def disable_event():
    pass

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Click me to close", command = close_program)
btn.pack()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't like using root.overrideredirect(True) because then the window is stuck in the top left corner of my screen when executing.

However, I will try "pass" within root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event). I was using return earlier.

Comment: @JoshuaVanDeren: You can use `overrideredirect(True)` and then you can create your own custom toolbar. Its a bit of work but is very customizable.

Comment: EDIT: using pass still does not fix the problem. The progressbar is still frozen when the user holds down [ X ]

@Sierra Mountain Tech Are you sure you can while the progressbar is in a thread? I have run across an issue several times where it needs to be in the main thread.

Comment: @JoshuaVanDeren: If you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can then test I can come up with a working solution.

Comment: Sure thing. If I have time, I'll produce an example of this.

Answer (score 5):

another way to achieve this on windows:

```
#!python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading, time

import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import windll, wintypes

GWL_STYLE = -16
WS_CHILD = 0x40000000
WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000

SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020
SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010
SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002
SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001

# write short names for functions and specify argument and return types
GetWindowLong = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW
GetWindowLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
GetWindowLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT)

SetWindowLong = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW
SetWindowLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
SetWindowLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT, wintypes.ULONG)

SetWindowPos = windll.user32.SetWindowPos

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=400, mode="determinate", maximum=100)
        self.pb.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Remove buttons", command=self.remove_buttons).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Add buttons", command=self.add_buttons).pack()


    def start(self):
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.loop)
        self.t.start()

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            for num in range(0, 100):
                self.pb['value']=num
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def _get_hwnd(self):
        w_id = self.winfo_id() # gets handle
        style = GetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE) # get existing style
        newstyle = style & ~WS_CHILD # remove child style
        res = SetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE, newstyle) # set new style
        res = SetWindowPos(w_id, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
        hwnd = int(self.wm_frame(), 16) # find handle of parent
        res = SetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE, style) # set back to old style
        res = SetWindowPos(w_id, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
        return hwnd # return parents handle

    def remove_buttons(self):
        hwnd = self._get_hwnd()
        style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) # get existing style
        style = style & ~WS_SYSMENU
        res = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style)
        res = SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)

    def add_buttons(self):
        hwnd = self._get_hwnd()
        style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) # get existing style
        style = style | WS_SYSMENU
        res = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style)
        res = SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.start()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looks complicated, but seems feasible!

Comment: it looks complicated because tkinter doesn't play nicely with the windows api for getting a handle to the parent window, the hackery to get around this is in the `_get_hwnd` function, and the add or remove buttons functions get the style of the window as it is, then adds of removes the styles needed to take away all the buttons in the titlebar, because it modifies the existing style this should work with most window styles

Comment: @JamesKent Why didn't you just use `hwnd = GetParent(super().winfo_id())`? It looks like it gets the window handle. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819099/11106801).