# Is it possible to NOT let the user close a Tkinter Window?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it poosible to hide the buttons for closing a window for the user?
The user should **not** be able to close the window. Is this possible with python tkinter?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467143/disable-exit-or-x-in-tkinter-window), you can do it by disabling the (x) button with a simple pass.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

def disable_event():
    pass

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

root.mainloop()
```

Or you could remove the toolbar with `root.overrideredirect(True)`.

Comment: FWIW: this is a good place for a `lambda`, which avoids the need to define a function that does nothing. `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: None)`. But `overrideredirect` is probably cleaner!