# Is there an way to remove exit button on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, exit

Can I remove an exit button on Tkinter?

I wanna make an Inexhaustible Tkinter window.
I used this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def on_closing():
   pass

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

is there a way for the *REMOVING* exit button

Comment: Have you tried  `root.overrideredirect(True)`?

Comment: @schwartz721 no, how to do that?

Comment: Just above `root.mainloop()` try adding `root.overrideredirect(True)`. This should remove the top bar entirely, so the exit button will be gone. Might not work depending on your OS though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Exit (or \[ X \]) in tkinter Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467143/disable-exit-or-x-in-tkinter-window)

Comment: @Alas435 no, i do not need Disable button, i need REMOVE button.