# How to make a window with no X button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a window with no X button in Tkinter,
[image]

like the image, see how it lacks an X button, i am trying to figure out how to make a window
not have an X button.

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using?

Comment: @HALF9000 i am using Python's tkinter library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make such a window using Tkinter, however, you can delete the title bar and make it again, without the close button:

Here is some code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry('400x100+200+200')

title_bar = Frame(root, bg='white', relief='raised', bd=2)

window = Canvas(root, bg='black')

title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

In case of Mac computers:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.overrideredirect(1)
root.overrideredirect(0)
root.geometry('400x100+200+200')

title_bar = Frame(root, bg='white', relief='raised', bd=2)

window = Canvas(root, bg='black')

title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Note: This code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter).

If you run this program, you will find a custom title bar that doesn't have the close button.

Comment: What is the point of moving around the title bar, when the OP never asked about it. BTW this solution doesn't work for me!

Comment: Are you using a Mac computer? If you're using a Mac computer, you'll have to add another statement (as edited above), and BTW, I've removed the function of moving the title bar around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the title bar, the way you want with Tkinter, you will have to turn off the title bar and rebuild all those methods from scratch.

But for this case of disabling "Close Button",  you have 3 options: using a callback function, or using `root.overriderdirect(True)`, or using `root.attributes('-disabled', True)`
[Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467143/disable-exit-or-x-in-tkinter-window)

---

Simplest method I would suggest to disable "X" button is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win= Tk()

win.geometry("750x250")
def close_win():
   win.destroy()
def disable_event():
   pass
#Create a button to close the window
btn = ttk.Button(win, text ="Click here to Close",command=close_win)
btn.pack()
#Disable the Close Window Control Icon
win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)
win.mainloop()
```