# How to keep TKinter grab_set() from falling through before closing messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a custom message box that works the same as askyesno() (in preparation for a bigger project), and grab_set() doesn't maintain control of the program until the user selects a button. How can I get grab_set() to retain control of the program flow until the user clicks on a button in the message box, and what's the best way to return the user's choice to the calling function?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu, ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

class Test(tk.Tk):
    def builtin(self, wtitle):
        print('Button One')
        answer = askyesno(title=wtitle, message='Click something', icon='info')
        print('User pressed: %s' % answer)


    def custom(self, wtitle):
        print('Button Two')
        answer = popup_msg(self, wtitle, 'Click to close')
        print('User pressed: %s' % answer)
        
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title('Test')
        self.geometry('300x100')

        frame   = ttk.Frame(self)
        
        button_one   = ttk.Button(self, text='Built-in',
                                  command=lambda: self.builtin('Built-In'))
        button_two   = ttk.Button(self, text='Custom',
                                  command=lambda: self.custom('Custom'))

        button_one.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        button_two.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        frame.pack()


def popup_msg(root, wtitle, msg):
    ret = False
    
    def test_func(val):
        popup.destroy()
        return val
        
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    popup.wm_title(wtitle)
    popup.geometry("300x100")
   
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    button1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Yes", command = lambda: test_func(True))
    button2 = ttk.Button(popup, text="No", command = lambda: test_func(False))
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()

    popup.grab_set()
    return ret


app = Test()
app.mainloop()
```

The above code creates two buttons - Built-in calls askyesno(), while Custom calls a function for making a messagebox. The Built-in function prints out "Button One," then displays the message box. When the use picks yes or no, the box disappears and the function prints the user's choice. With Custom, the function prints "Button Two" and "User pressed False", and opens the custom window. Clicking on Yes or No closes the window, but has no effect on what gets printed out.

Comment: What do you expect `grap_set` to do? Because I believe your assumption on it is quite different from it's actual use case.

Comment: `grab_set` says "this window is the only active window for my application".  It doesn't affect other applications.

Comment: What I want is to open a messagebox with two buttons, "Yes" and "No". I want the messagebox to return True if the user clicks "Yes," and False if the user clicks "No." In both cases, clicking on a button should also close the messagebox. Right now, the messagebox returns False immediately on being called, before the user clicks either of the buttons. I initially tried using popup.mainloop(), and that prevented the user selection from printing until after the application closed.

Comment: `wait_variable` is suitable for your case. But it can lead to unintended behaviour if you are not careful.

Comment: @tsoj Look at [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/Bismuth-184/blob/main/src/bettertk/messagebox.py). I used `mainloop()`. I call `.quit()` when the user chooses yes/no to exit from the `mainloop`. That is the key - calling `quit()` you want to stop the last `mainloop()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Does this use of .quit() only work with classes? I haven't used super before. I assume it's a "class thing."

Comment: @tsoj `.quit()` is just another function like `.mainloop()`. Calling it stops the last `.mainloop()` called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can subclass `simpledialog.Dialog` to create custom Dialog and override the required methods.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu, simpledialog, ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno


class Test(tk.Tk):
    def builtin(self, wtitle):
        print("Button One")
        answer = askyesno(title=wtitle, message="Click something", icon="info")
        print("User pressed: %s" % answer)

    def custom(self, wtitle):
        print("Button Two")
        answer = popup_msg(
            self, wtitle="My Custom MessageBox", msg="This is custom MessageBox"
        )
        print("User pressed: %s" % answer)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("Test")
        self.geometry("300x100")

        frame = ttk.Frame(self)

        button_one = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Built-in", command=lambda: self.builtin("Built-In")
        )
        button_two = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Custom", command=lambda: self.custom("Custom")
        )

        button_one.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        button_two.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        frame.pack()


class MessageBox(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sample_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.sample_var.set("No")

        self.label_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_var.set(kwargs.pop("msg", "default msg"))

        simpledialog.Dialog.__init__(
            self, master, title=kwargs.pop("wtitle", "default title"), *args, **kwargs
        )

    def body(self, master):
        """create dialog body.

        return widget that should have initial focus.
        This method should be overridden, and is called
        by the __init__ method.
        """

        tk.Label(master, textvariable=self.label_var).grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

        self.btn_yes = tk.Button(
            master, text="Yes", command=lambda: self._button_yes(master)
        ).grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.btn_no = tk.Button(
            master, text="No", command=lambda: self._button_no(master)
        ).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def _button_yes(self, master):
        self.sample_var.set("Yes")
        self.ok()

    def _button_no(self, master):
        self.sample_var.set("No")
        self.ok()

    def validate(self):
        """validate the data

        This method is called automatically to validate the data before the
        dialog is destroyed. By default, it always validates OK.
        """

        return 1  # override

    def apply(self):
        """process the data

        This method is called automatically to process the data, *after*
        the dialog is destroyed. By default, it does nothing.
        """
        self.result = self.sample_var.get()

    def buttonbox(self):
        """Override default simpledialog.Dialog buttons"""
        pass


def popup_msg(root, wtitle, msg):
    res = MessageBox(app, wtitle=wtitle, msg=msg)
    return res.result


app = Test()
app.mainloop()
```

---

When you click on `Custom` button, you shall see:

[image]

Then when you click `Yes`/`No` the dialog closes and the program prints `User pressed: Yes/No`

Comment: After looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/81bc802a46f6f2725913ac31b4cec0ec3a0e3732/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py#L145), it looks like [`.wait_window()`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/tkwait.html) is being used in order to wait for the user to finish interacting with the dialog.

Comment: Also why are you using a `StringVar` instead of a basic python string to hold the result?

Comment: @TheLizzard I followed the tutorials on tkinter and `StringVar` is very versatile. Perhaps not useful in this simple  example, but you can attach `StringVar` to a Label and it will update automatically etc. Perhaps the "value" of the Dialog comes from text input, so `StringVar` is then more useful. More:https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/

Comment: I agree that `StringVar` is sometimes useful but unless you call `trace`/attach it to 2+ widgets, it can be avoided. In this case it makes it a bit harder for people new to `tkinter` to understand.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely - I copied over your new code to my file and it works right. I'll need to sit down and take the time to understand exactly what's going on, but right now, thanks! I assume that the primary behavior of the code doesn't change if I add new widgets, like checkboxes or a listbox/scrollbar combo. One of my goals is to have a messagebox with a listbox/scrollbar for multiple selections, and next to it buttons for Accept and Cancel.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely - One question. Where can I find the documentation that describes validate(), apply(), etc.? I need to modify your example to handle when the user closes the messagebox window by clicking the "X" button instead of clicking "Yes" or "No". Right now, MessageBox returns "None" for that case. Thanks.

Comment: @tsoj You can use official Python `tkinter` documentation, e.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html For the disabling close [x] button look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467143/disable-exit-or-x-in-tkinter-window

Comment: @Andrej Kesely - Thanks for your reply! I don't want to disable the close button - I want to intercept it, like with the validate() and apply() methods. Ideally, I'd like something like:

def close(self):
     self.result = 0

Comment: @tsoj The easiest way I can think of is to check if the `res.result` is `None`. If it's `None`, the dialog was closed without clicking on the buttons.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely - Ok, I can do it that way, too. Thanks again!